Email Verifcation is working properly on my localhost but not when I hosted it
My email verification is working properly on my localhost but when I hosted it, it is not working. When I clicked the link "Verify Email" on the email the user received, it always shows "Invalid token or expired." the database connection is same with the username, password, database name and servername on the database I created on the hosting provider. Here is my code:
<?php
include 'db_connection.php';

// Check if token is provided in the URL
if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
    $token = $_GET['token'];

    // Prepare SQL statement to fetch email associated with the token
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT email FROM email_verification WHERE token = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $token);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Check if a row is returned
    if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
        // Fetch Email
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $email = $row['email'];

        // Mark the email as verified in the users table
        $update_stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE users SET verified = 1 WHERE email = ?");
        $update_stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $update_stmt->execute();

        // Delete the verification token from the email_verification table
        $delete_stmt = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM email_verification WHERE token = ?");
        $delete_stmt->bind_param("s", $token);
        $delete_stmt->execute();

        // Close statements
        $stmt->close();
        $update_stmt->close();
        $delete_stmt->close();

        // Redirect to the Log in page
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Invalid token or token expired.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Token not provided.";
}

// Close database connection
if (isset($connection)) {
    $connection->close();
}


This isn't anything to do with PHPMailer. You need to figure out what's up with your token, for example by manually looking up the token from the email in the database and making sure it actually exists. Don't assume that your DB connection is working - check it before worrying about things that happen later.

Yes the token exists. It is working fine on my localhost, but when I hosted it on the webhost it is not working as it works in the localhost.

As I said, test it on your webhost: you don't have an email problem, you have a database problem. Check exactly what is in the database on your host and confirm that it contains the token you're looking for.
